# How do I put formatting into text that I copy paste via autohotkey

Tags: formatting, autohotkey

I have an autohotkey script that I trigger via a hotkey. It reads data from a .txt file and then pastes the data into the active window. The active window can be a note from Evernote.

The textfile is simple unicode but I want to have colored text as a end product.
How do I get there? How do I format the text.

If it matters, the script runs on windows.

Comment: How would you manually set text color in evernote?

Comment: No, I want to have the text color be set automatically.

Comment: I mean how does the color formatting work in ever note? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @JoelFazio I can copypaste blue text on this website and when I copy that text into Evernote it keeps it's blue color. From that perspective Windows somehow has an internal representation for colored text and I want to use that representation via autohotkey.

Comment: The Clipboard has the ability to hold formatting data or even image data. Try `myVar := ClipBoardAll` see this [link](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Transform.htm#Unicode) for more info on using the data.